# How select a drop down but element type is input using Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm currently using a robot framework and have a project that using mdbootstrap as front end.
However, I'm facing trouble that their dropdown select element is using input as type.

```
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-0c5c119c-fe7f-4c45-8db9-5af047606d66" value="Choose your option" xpath="1">
<ul id="select-options-0c5c119c-fe7f-4c45-8db9-5af047606d66" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 427.038px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;" xpath="1"><li class="disabled"><span class="filtrable">Choose your option</span></li><li class="active"><span class="filtrable">Option 1</span></li><li class=""><span class="filtrable">Option 2</span></li><li class=""><span class="filtrable">Option 3</span></li></ul>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" style="" xpath="1">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
```

So I want to ask how to select that kind of dropdown type?

I've tried :

- Directly select the class "mdb-select initialized" but will throw error element not found
- Also, tried to click the dropdown element first so the option is activated, but the same result.

Does anyone have a solution or approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

By the way You can use Xpath as a locator for select the value . 
But i recomend to ask your developer team to set the ID or Name Becuase it's will make you more easy to select the value from this dropdown .

```
select from list by value  xpath=/html/body/select      2
```

Comment: if I ask the dev where to set the ID?
in the  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" > or in the select type? 
because when I select directly the select type '<select class="mdb-select initialized" style="" xpath="1">' the element is not found

Comment: Put in select type . Just set the name for this tag .